# XSLT1.0 Remove repeat nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to apply Muenchian grouping to eliminate duplicate nodes, but I seem not to be able to make it work.

Input:

```
<GetUsersByRoleRspMsg>
   <UserList>
      <User>
         <UserId>PPAUSER1</UserId>
         <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>         
      </User>
      <User>
         <UserId>PPAUSER1</UserId>
         <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>         
      </User>      
   </UserList>
</GetUsersByRoleRspMsg>
```

Required:

```
<GetUsersByRoleRspMsg>
   <UserList>
      <User>
         <UserId>PPAUSER1</UserId>
         <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>         
      </User>      
   </UserList>
</GetUsersByRoleRspMsg>
```

The critical part of my code is

```
<xsl:key name="userIdEmailPair" 
         match="User" 
         use="concat(UserId,' ',Email)"/> 

<xsl:copy> 
  <xsl:for-each select="User[
    count(. | key('userIdEmailPair',
                  concat(UserId,' ',Email))[1])
    = 1]"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of writing the entire code for you.

Comment: I tried with:<xsl:key name="userIdEmailPair" match="User" use="concat(UserId,' ',Email)"/>

 <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="User[count(. | key('userIdEmailPair',concat(UserId,' ',Email))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>

Comment: Please edit your question and post the **complete** code there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your grouping code. If you try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="userIdEmailPair" match="User" use="concat(UserId,' ',Email)"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UserList">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="User[count(. | key('userIdEmailPair',concat(UserId,' ',Email))[1]) = 1]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get the result you're looking for.

Of course, you could shorten the last template to:

```
<xsl:template match="UserList">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="User[count(. | key('userIdEmailPair',concat(UserId,' ',Email))[1]) = 1]"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```